# Twitter's typeahead-bloodhound: What is the equivalent of "%QUERY" when using ajax.data and POST?

Tags: jquery, post, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

If one uses Bloodhound with GET:

```
// Typeahead
personsBloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (person) { return person.name; },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/ajax/Persons/List?nameContains=%QUERY',
        ajax: {
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $(".searching-person").show();
            },
            data: {
                "pageSize": 4,
                "otherParam1": "blah",
                "otherParam2": "bleh",
            }
        },
        filter: function (response) {
            $(".searching-person").hide();
            return response.persons;
        }
    }
});
```

One simply uses %QUERY in the URL.


Now....
**If one uses Bloodhound with POST, what should I use instead of %QUERY?**

```
// Typeahead
personsBloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (person) { return person.name; },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/ajax/Persons/List',
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                $(".searching-person").show();
            },
            data: {
                "nameContains": ....WHAT GOES HERE?????......
                "pageSize": 4,
                "otherParam1": "blah",
                "otherParam2": "bleh",
            }
        },
        filter: function (response) {
            $(".searching-person").hide();
            return response.persons;
        }
    }
});
```

If it was not clear, the question is:
**What is the equivalent of `%QUERY` when using POST within Bloodhound's remote?**

The documentation isn't clear about this, (proof):
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote

Also tried using:

```
 "nameContains": $("#my-input-that-uses-typeahead").val(),
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to alter the URL somehow, otherwise the bloodhound wont send an other request (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24025789/2175370) and livesearch/typeahead wont work.

So `("#my-input-that-uses-typeahead").val()` works just fine in combination with a dynamic URL (e.g.`http://127.0.0.1:1234/REST_API/_search?useless=%QUERY`) and a `beforeSend`-function in the ajax setttings.

I gonna file an issue about this behaviour. Using the bloodhound for POST-requests ist VERY awkward and takes away the simplicity intended with typeahead.js.

**EDIT:**

Also make sure you set the new value for the data in `beforeSend` and set `settings.hasContent = true`. **Otherwise the initial data will be used.**

Example on how it's done: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/542#issuecomment-29995960.

Comment: kind of ugly, but ok... accepted, also in the link the author of typeahead supports your answer

Comment: He also answered me on Github: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/848#issuecomment-53574322. It seems he wants to change this behaviour with the next release.

Answer (score 1):

**Equivalent of `%QUERY` when using POST within Bloodhound's remote is `query`.**

Here is a simple example (with detailed explanation) where you can use it for both `GET` and `POST`. As you can see I have declared a variable `isExtendUrl`. If this is set to `true` then the query (what you type) will be added to the end of the url (you have to give the `myurl` somehow).

The next variable is `isRequestMethod`. If this is set to `POST`, you can use bloodhound for `POST` calls else you can use it for `GET` calls. As you can see `prepare` function has two parameters `query` and `setting`. `query` is the one what you type. If you just want the `POST` call without `GET` move `prepare` key value pair inside `remote` object.

So, if you have to use `JSON` body as `{gender: 'MALE', name: 'what is typed'}` for your `POST` call. You can have an initial query object with all your key value pairs eg: `initialQuery = {gender: 'MALE'}`, and the key `searchKey` which should be added to `initialQuery` when searching, could be added on `prepare` like `initialQuery[searchKey] = query`.

Finally, if the response object of your `POST` call is an object and you have to extract a specific key value use `filter`. Eg: Say your response object is

```
{
  status: 'some status', 
  content: [{array}, {of}, {objects}, ...], 
  someKey: someValue
}
```

and you have to get `content`, then return `data.content`. Here is a full example

```
let isExtendUrl = true; //to add query at the end of the url, usually used with GET
let isRequestMethod = 'POST';
let initialQuery = {gender: 'MALE'};
let searchKey = 'name';

let bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: {
        url: isExtendUrl ? myurl + '%QUERY' : myurl,
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (data) {
            return $.map(data.content, function (obj) {
                return obj;
            });
        }
    }
});

if (isRequestMethod == 'POST') {
    let prepare = function (query, settings) {
        initialQuery[searchKey] = query;
        settings.type = "POST";
        settings.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        settings.data = JSON.stringify(initialQuery);

        return settings;
    }
    bloodhound.remote.prepare = prepare;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, after further looking at bloodhound the wildcard is just what to replace not the value.

It doesn't store the query string anywhere. On `queryChanged` fires and filters remote response. Looks like you'll have to get the query yourself.

```
"nameContains": $('input#search').val()
```

Comment: so how do I pass the wildcard in a remote that uses a POST ajax?

Comment: Good point, the wildcard was just what to replace in the GET url, not the query to send.